# Product topology on a function space, characterization of opens.

Tags: general-topology

Suppose we have a function space $B^A$, and we give both $A$ and $B$ the discrete topology. Viewing the function space as the product $\prod_{a \in A} B$, this gives it the product topology. Now I want to show that $U \subset B^A$ is open iff there exists a finite subset $E \subset A$ such that for every map $g : A \to B$ with $g \mid_E = f \mid_E$ we have that $g \in U$.

For the $(\Rightarrow)$ direction, suppose $U$ is open. Then it is of the form $\prod_{a \in A} B \times B \times E_1 \times \ldots \times B \times E_n \times B \times \ldots$ for some finite $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, with $E_i \subset B$ any subset. Hence, we can take the set $E = \{1,\ldots,n\} \subset A$, and if $g(a_i) = f(a_i)$ for each of the coordinates, we have that $g \in U$.

But I am stuck at proving the reverse.

Comment: What is your default topology on a function space? You don't specify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems here. First, you never said what $f$ is. I can think of two things that you might have intended:

1. $U\subseteq B^A$ is open iff there are a finite $E\subseteq A$ and an $f:A\to B$ such that $g\in U$ whenever $g\in B^A$ and $g\upharpoonright E=f\upharpoonright E$.
2. $U\subseteq B^A$ is open iff for each $f\in U$ there is a finite $E\subseteq A$ such that $g\in U$ whenever $g\in B^A$ and $g\upharpoonright E=f\upharpoonright E$.

For each $f\in B^A$ and finite $E\subseteq A$ let $B(f,E)=\{g\in B^A:g\upharpoonright E=f\upharpoonright E\}$; it is easy to verify that $B(f,E)$ is a basic open set in $B^A$ and that every basic open set in $B^A$ is of this form, because

$$B(f,E)=\prod_{a\in A}U_a\;,$$

where

$$U_a=\begin{cases}
\{f(a)\},&\text{if }a\in E\\
B,&\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$

Thus, (2) just says that $U$ is open iff it is union of basic open nbhds of its elements and is therefore true.

(1), however, says that $U\subseteq B^A$ is open iff there is at least one set $B(f,E)$ contained in $U$, and this is false. To see this, fix $a_0\in A$ and distinct $b_0,b_1\in B$, and let $f\in B^A$ be defined by $f(a_0)=b_1$, and $f(a)=b_0$ if $a\in A\setminus\{a_0\}$. Let $g\in B^A$ be the constant function such that $g(a)=b_0$ for each $a\in A$. Finally, let

$$U=B(f,\{a_0\})\cup\{g\}=\left\{h\in B^A:h(a_0)=b_1\text{ or }h=g\right\}\;;$$

then $U$ contains the basic open set $B(f,\{a_0\})$, but $U$ is not open, because it does not contain any open nbhd of $g$.

Whichever of these you intended, you’ve made a fundamental error at the beginning of your argument: it is not true that every open set in the product has the form that you describe; those sets are a base for the product topology, so every open set in the product is a **union** of such sets. For a concrete example, let $A=B=\Bbb N$, so that $B^A$ is the space of sequences of non-negative integers, and let $U=\{x\in B^A:x(0)=0\text{ or }x(1)=1\}$; then

$$U=\{x\in B^A:x(0)=0\}\cup\{x\in B^A:x(1)=1\}$$

is the union of two basic open sets but is not itself expressible as a product of open sets in $B$ in which all but finitely many factors $B$ itself.

**Added:** If you’re visually oriented, you may find it useful to have a way to visualize infinite products. The diagram below is a way to think about $\Bbb N^{\Bbb N}$. The factor spaces are represented vertically, as parallel copies of $\Bbb N$. A point in $\Bbb N^{\Bbb N}$ picks out one point in each of those copies; the red points in the diagram, for instance, correspond to a point $f\in\Bbb N^{\Bbb N}$ such that $f(0)=3$, $f(1)=1$, $f(2)=2$, $f(3)=0$, $f(4)=3$, $f(5)=1$, and $f(6)=4$. The basic open set $B(f(\{1,4\})$ consists of all $g\in\Bbb N^{\Bbb N}$ such that $g(1)=1$ and $g(4)=3$, i.e., all of the points of the product that pass through the two points of the diagram marked with $\color{red}\oplus$.

$$\begin{array}{c|cc}
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
4&\bullet&\bullet&\bullet&\bullet&\bullet&\bullet&\color{red}\bullet&\cdots\\
3&\color{red}\bullet&\bullet&\bullet&\bullet&\color{red}\oplus&\bullet&\bullet&\cdots\\
2&\bullet&\bullet&\color{red}\bullet&\bullet&\bullet&\bullet&\bullet&\cdots\\
1&\bullet&\color{red}\oplus&\bullet&\bullet&\bullet&\color{red}\bullet&\bullet&\cdots\\
0&\bullet&\bullet&\bullet&\color{red}\bullet&\bullet&\bullet&\bullet&\cdots\\\hline
&\Bbb N_0&\Bbb N_1&\Bbb N_2&\Bbb N_3&\Bbb N_4&\Bbb N_5&\Bbb N_6&\cdots
\end{array}$$

Comment: That's clear, thank you! Indeed, I meant the second point, but forgot to specify what $f$ is. The counter-example was informative. I'm firstly becoming acquainted with this topology so I haven't got much intuition for it yet. The example of $\mathbb{N}$ is helpful to think in somewhat more concrete terms, I hadn't considered that yet.

Comment: @Sigurd: You’re welcome! Infinite products can be a bit tricky to think about. In case you’re visually oriented, I’m adding a diagram to my answer to show you one way to think about them.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. Indeed, I like to think visually about concepts, so that is very helpful to enhance my intuition!

Comment: @Sigurd: Glad it helps. It’s a trick that I learned from my thesis adviser 50 years ago, and I’ve always found it helpful despite **not** being very visual.

Comment: Yes this diagram is really nice in fact, thank you for sharing. In fact, after you mentioned the space $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$, I was suddenly reminded of the space $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$, that I once saw in measure theory. We defined a 'cylinder', for example [011], as all sequences in the space starting with 0,1,1. Then taking the sigma algebra generated by all cylinders. At that time I never saw a connection with topology, but now I suddenly realized this is just the sigma algebra generated by all basic opens, just like the Lebesque measure on $\mathbb{R}$ is generated by all $(a,b)$.